# Is "fare you well" still used in Norfolk?

Tags: phrases, literature

[Jean Rhys's](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/apr/14/jean-rhys-brief-survey-short-story) story "Till September Petronella" contains the following passage:

> 'Fare you well,' he said. 'That's what they say in Norfolk, where I come from.'
>
> 'Good-bye.'
>
> 'No, say fare you well.'

The story was published in 1968 in the collection [*Tigers Are Better-Looking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigers_Are_Better-Looking) but written in the 1950s. I suspect the stories in that volume actually reflect an earlier time period.

Some people on the [WordReference forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/and-thus-fare-you-well.3334950/) also found the phrase in a novel about the last days of Anne Boleyn and appear to assume it may have been in use at the time of Henry VIII.

However, I was wondering if the phrase "fare you well" is still in use in Norfolk. (Not necessarily by everybody; it might sound old-fashioned to younger generations.)

Comment: I think it would be considered very archaic in Norfolk and everywhere else, for that matter.

Comment: My husband, now in his late 50s, was born in Norfolk and has spent much of his life living in various parts of the county. He has never heard it used (in either rural or urban settings), and very much doubts whether it has been used at all in the last century.